# R Shiny Dashboard Header dropdown buttons lead to scrolling

Tags: layout, header, dropdown, shinydashboard

The buttons in the header of my shiny dashboard should be easy to see and press. However, at the moment the dropdownbuttons pop up within the header and people have to scroll in order to see the buttons.
Below you will find a reproducible code sample.

Here is some further information on my session:

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
shinythemes_1.1.2
shinyWidgets_0.5.3
shinyBS_0.61

```
if (interactive()) {
library(shiny)
require(dplyr)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
  # A dashboard header with 3 dropdown menus
  header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Dashboard Demo",
   tags$li(class = "dropdown",tags$br(),
                               dropdownButton(inputId = "mydropdown",label = "",# style="minimal",
                                              # label="Language",
                                              circle = FALSE,
                                              icon = icon("globe"),#,status = "primary", 
                                              badgeStatus = "success",
                                              
                                              prettyRadioButtons(inputId = "selected_language", label="",
                                                                 choiceNames = list(
                                                                   HTML("<font color='black'>Deutsch</font>"), 
                                                                   tags$span(style = "color:black", "English")
                                                                 ),
                                                                 choiceValues =  c( "de",  "en"), 
                                                                 # inline=TRUE,
                                                                 selected = "en"
                                              )
                                              
                                              )# useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert #
                               
                               ,
                               block = TRUE) ,
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",introjsUI(),    tags$br(),actionBttn(inputId = "Help",
                                                                    # color = "primary",
                                                                    style = 
                                                                      "minimal",
                                                                    icon = icon("question", lib="font-awesome"),label ="Help", size="sm"),
            block = TRUE),tags$li( class = "dropdown",tags$br(),
                                   
                                   introBox(dropdownMenu(
                                     type = "notifications", 
                                     icon = icon("envelope", lib = "glyphicon"),
                                     badgeStatus = NULL,
                                     headerText = "App maintainer contact:",
                                     notificationItem("TestMailAdress", icon("envelope", lib = "glyphicon"))
                                   ), data.step=5, data.intro = "Any further questions? Contact us!")
            ))
    
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      header,
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody()
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
  )
}
# }
```

Comment: in order to help others better focus on the actual problem you are experiencing, please avoid to clutter the code you provide with unnecessary libraries. I edited this to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answers. I figured it out myself. The introBox referring to the header button messed things up. So without the helping window it works... still would be nice to have the introBox working, but I guess it is just not supported yet...

```
if (interactive()) {
library(shiny)
require(dplyr)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
  # A dashboard header with 3 dropdown menus
  header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Dashboard Demo",
   tags$li(class = "dropdown",tags$br(),
                               dropdownButton(inputId = "mydropdown",label = "",# style="minimal",
                                              # label="Language",
                                              circle = FALSE,
                                              icon = icon("globe"),#,status = "primary", 
                                              badgeStatus = "success",
                                              
                                              prettyRadioButtons(inputId = "selected_language", label="",
                                                                 choiceNames = list(
                                                                   HTML("<font color='black'>Deutsch</font>"), 
                                                                   tags$span(style = "color:black", "English")
                                                                 ),
                                                                 choiceValues =  c( "de",  "en"), 
                                                                 # inline=TRUE,
                                                                 selected = "en"
                                              )
                                              
                                              )# useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert #
                               
                               ,
                               block = TRUE) ,
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",introjsUI(),    tags$br(),actionBttn(inputId = "Help",
                                                                    # color = "primary",
                                                                    style = 
                                                                      "minimal",
                                                                    icon = icon("question", lib="font-awesome"),label ="Help", size="sm"),
            block = TRUE),tags$li( class = "dropdown",tags$br(),
                                   
                                  dropdownMenu(
                                     type = "notifications", 
                                     icon = icon("envelope", lib = "glyphicon"),
                                     badgeStatus = NULL,
                                     headerText = "App maintainer contact:",
                                     notificationItem("TestMailAdress", icon("envelope", lib = "glyphicon"))
                                   )
            ))
    
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      header,
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody()
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
  )
}
# }
```